# Get index of DataFrame for rows that are identical to elements of an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame (temp) and an array (x), whose elements correspond to some of the lines of the DataFrame. I want to get the indexes of the DataFrame whose corresponding records are identical to the elements of the array:

For example:

```
 temp = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [4,5,6,7], "C": [7,8,9,10]})

    A   B   C
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
3   4   7   10

x = np.array([[1,4,7], [3,6,9]])
```

It should return the indexes: 0 and 2.

I was trying unsuccessfully with this:

```
temp.loc[temp.isin(x[0])].index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy broadcasting:

```py
array = temp.to_numpy()[:, None]
mask = (array == x).all(axis=-1).any(axis=-1)
temp.index[mask]
```

Comment: Your solution is general and works perfectly. I put a simple example, but applied to my real case the other answers give wrong values (it may be because of the indexes that in my real case do not go from 0 and in a sequence of 1, it may be because of the repeated records in the DataFrame, I must inspect in more detail). Your answer works correctly!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I would convert to Multiindex and then to isin with `np.where`

```
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(temp[['A','B','C']])
out = np.where(i.isin(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(x.T)))[0]
```

---

```
print(out)
#[0 2]
```

Or with merge:

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
out = temp.reset_index().merge(pd.DataFrame(x,columns=cols)).loc[:,'index'].tolist()
```

Or  with `np.isin` and `all`

```
out = temp.index[np.isin(temp[['A','B','C']],x).all(1)]
```

Comment: @user140259 Sorry but I did not understand

Comment: @user140259 it check if all the elements in axis 1 is True else returns False.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to match entire rows of the `DataFrame` to rows in the `numpy array`, you can convert the DataFrame to an array and then use enumerate to loop and return the indices:

```
temp_arr = temp.to_numpy()

for idx, row in enumerate(temp_arr):
    if row in x:
        print(idx)
```

Output:

```
0
2
```

A more elegant way using list comprehension would be:

```
idx_list = [i for i, row in enumerate(temp_arr) if row in x ]    
print(idx_list)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2]
```